# Disk-backed STL container classes?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, stl, on-disk

I enjoy developing algorithms using the STL, however, I have this recurring problem where my data sets are too large for the heap.

I have been searching for drop-in replacements for STL containers and algorithms which are disk-backed, i.e. the data structures on stored on disk rather than the heap.

A friend recently pointed me towards [stxxl](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net). Before I get too involved with it... Are any other disk-backed STL replacements available that I should be considering?

**NOTE: I'm not interested in persistence or embedded databases. Please don't mention boost::serialization, POST++, Relational Template Library, Berkeley DB, sqlite, etc. I am aware of these projects and use them when they are appropriate for my purposes.**

*UPDATE: Several people have mentioned memory-mapping files and using a custom allocator, good suggestions BTW, but I would point them to the discussion [here](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2002/11/39388.php) where David Abraham suggests that custom iterators would be needed for disk-backed containers. Meaning the custom allocator approach isn't likely to work.*

Comment: If your datasets are too large for the heap, you should consider whether your system architecture is correct (e.g., whether to move to a 64-bit system; these are more common now than when the question was asked). You should also consider whether the STL is the right approach; it may be making assumptions about dataset size which don't hold for you.

Comment: @Donal He might not be reserving the correct amount of memory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have implemented some thing very similar. Implementing the iterators is the most challenging. I used **[boost::iterator_facade](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_facade.html)** to implement the iterators. Using `boost::iterator_facade` you can **easy adapt** any cached on **disk data structures** to have a STL container interface.

Comment: I use Boost, but iterator_facade is new to me. I'll have to take a look at that, thanks for sharing.

Comment: Care to share the implementation?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share that code. However if you have any questions I would be more than happy to help.

Answer (score 8):

I've never had to do anything quite like this, but It might be possible to do what you want to do by writing a custom allocator that makes use of a memory mapped files to back your data.

See [boost::interprocesses](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.mapped_file) for docs on their easy to use implementation of memory mapped files, [this Dr. Dobbs article](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184406243) for a detailed discussion on writing allocators, and [this IEEE Software column](http://www.spinellis.gr/blog/20101030/) for a description of the problem and [example code](http://www.spinellis.gr/blog/20101030/smap.cpp).

Comment: I am aware of the DDJ article, nice article. However, there was a discussion on boost's mailing list between Terpstra, Kuehl, & Abraham suggesting that custom iterators would be needed to deal with on-disk data structures... which kind of rules out the custom allocator approach.

Answer (score 3):

If (as you write) you're not interested in persistence the simplest solution would be to increase your heap size and use your operating system's virtual memory facilities.  The part of the heap that will not fit in your computer's physical memory will end up being paged on disk, giving you exactly what you want: normal STL access to data often stored on disk.  The operating system will take care of caching the most used pages in the physical memory and evicting to disk those you don't use a lot.  Your code will remain the same, and you can increase its performance simply by adding more physical memory.

To increase your heap size check your operating system's parameters, like ulimit(1) on Unix systems and System properties - Advanced - Performance - Advanced - Virtual Memory on Windows XP.  If you've hit the 32-bit 4GB limit consider moving to a 64 bit architecture or compiling your program for 64 bits.

Comment: I am a proficient systems administrator, I have considered the approach that you suggested. I have a amd64 machine running unix. I cannot afford adding more physical memory. My swap space is 2GB, my data set is 42GB, my hard drive is 1TB...

Comment: So, how about increasing your swap space?

Comment: Sure, I've thought about rebuilding my server to accommodate this project. However this isn't dedicated hardware, rather a machine used for general research. Beyond that, eventually collaborators will need to run the code too, and I don't think requiring them to rebuild their machines will work.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about the subject, but it might be possible to write an STL-like interface to a memory mapped file?

edit: This approach might be suitable if you're trying to get at a specific part of a huge file.  If you're attempting to do something with the entire file, you'll likely generate a huge number of page faults as you read in uncached parts of the file.

Comment: I have considered doing this... but I'd rather not write it myself if something useable has already been done.

Comment: I can appreciate not wanting to reinvent the wheel.  I'm not familiar with a library that does this; hopefully someone can recommend one.

Comment: I believe Boost.Interprocess can be used to write to a memory mapped file. Haven't actually tried it, though.