# Disk backed dictionary/cache for c#

Tags: c#, caching, disk-based

I'm looking for a drop in solution for caching large-ish amounts of data.

related questions but for different languages:

- [Python Disk-Based Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226693/python-disk-based-dictionary)
- [Disk-backed STL container classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149488/disk-backed-stl-container-classes)

Close question in different terms:

- [Looking for a simple standalone persistant dictionary implementation in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100235/looking-for-a-simple-standalone-persistant-dictionary-implementation-in-c)

I don't need (or want to pay anything for) persistence, transactions, thread safety or the like and want something that is not much more complex to use than a List<> or Dictionary<>.

If I have to write code, I'll just save everything off as files in the temp directory:

```
string Get(int i)
{
   File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(root,i.ToString());
}
```

In my cases in index will be an `int` (and they should be consecutive or close enough) and the data will be a `string` so I can get away with treating both a [POD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Data_Structures) and would rather go ultra-light and do exactly that.

The usage is that I have a sequence of 3k files (as in file #1 to #3000) totaling 650MB and need to do a diff for each step in the sequence. I expect that to total about the same or a little more and I don't want to keep all that in memory (larger cases may come along where I just can't).

---

A number of people have suggested different solutions for my problem. However none seem to be targeted at my little niche. The reasons that I'm looking at disk backed caching is because I'm expecting that my current use will use up 1/3 to 1/2 of my available address space. I'm worried that larger cases will just flat run out of space. I'm not worried about treading, persistence or replication. What I'm looking for is a minimal solution using a minimum of code, a minimal usage foot print, minimal in memory overhead and minimum complexity.

I'm starting to think I'm being overly optimistic.

Comment: Why not the filesystem? That is what is designed for...

Comment: I will if someone can't point me to something better that is already written.

Comment: Doesn't a disk-based cache kind of defeat the entire purpose of a caching mechanism?

Comment: Depends on where the data is coming from. If it's memoizing expensive computed value or data coming over a slow internet link it can be more than reasonable.

Comment: I just ran into a similar problem... Still hunting for a solution

Comment: Re: "Doesn't a disk-based cache kind of defeat the entire purpose of a caching mechanism?" -- Most caching is considered temporary. What if one wants the "index" to survive a reboot, for example? Maybe "caching" isn't the best word. "Disk/SSD-oriented dictionary library"? I've been looking for something similar to prototype "Dynamic Relational".

Answer (score 5):

What you really want is a B-Tree.
That's the primary data structure that a database uses.
It's designed to enable you to efficiently swap portions of a data structure to and from disk as needed.

I don't know of any widely used, high quality standalone B-Tree implementations for C#.

However, an easy way to get one would be to use a Sql Compact database. The Sql Compact engine will run in-process, so you don't need a seperate service running. It will give you a b-tree, but without all the headaches. You can just use SQL to access the data.

Comment: I'm not liking the overhead. See my edits but I could get away with a single in memory array look up and a single disk read per load so the B-Tree is overkill... in my case.

Comment: One advantage to using the in-proc DB is that it gives you access path independence. When you need to change what you data you store, or what keys you need to access it, you don't need to re-write a big chunk of your app

Comment: However, if you really feel that the stuff you need to do with the data is that simple, then I would think you could something from scratch that used Dictionary(of int, string), where the string was a file name, in about 2-3 hours of work....

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer - I am about to point you at a product that I am involved in.

I'm still working on the web site side of things, so there is not a lot of info, but [Serial Killer](http://www.thinkbottomup.com.au/site/Products/SerialKiller) would be a good fit for this.  I have examples that use .Net serialization (can supply examples), so writing a persistent map cache for .Net serializable objects would be trivial.

Enough shameless self promotion - if interested, use the contact link on the website.

Comment: +1 for related stuff but I'm looking more for ultra-light solutions (ideal would be where key & values are both POD and get stored as binary data blocks)

Comment: SerialKiller is pretty damn light - I'd hate for you to dismiss it for that reason!  The interface is basically a mapping from a key (system generated) to a binary stream.

Comment: The naive, probably buggy and extendability version of what I'm looking for (skipping the eviction policy stuff) could be done in about 30 LOC. I'd be impressed if you could get even half your feature list in nder that.

Comment: By "light" I refer more to runtime overheads, which are very low.  I haven't counted LOC, but the DLL's are under 500kb in total, which given the capability, is very lean.

Comment: skipping of iteration and recursion (unneeded in this case) LOC ~ execution time (for some values of LOC :)

Comment: I disagree.  Overcoming issues of fragmentation in the file system and caching strategies greatly affect execution time, so performance may be inversely proportional to LOC!

Answer (score 2):

This is very similar to my question

[Looking for a simple standalone persistant dictionary implementation in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100235/looking-for-a-simple-standalone-persistant-dictionary-implementation-in-c)

I don't think a library that exactly fits what you want exists, maybe its time for a new project on github.

Comment: Added link. How about you add a link the other way?

Comment: OTOH the motivation is different. you were looking for persistence, I'm wanting to store stuff on disk rather than in memory. Large overlap, but not quite the same.

Comment: No worries, I added a link from my post

Answer (score 1):

Here is a B-Tree implementation for .net: http://bplusdotnet.sourceforge.net/

Comment: An interesting project but still a lot heavier than I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [MS application block](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/MS_Application_Blocks.aspx) with disk based cache solution

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at NCache [here](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/caching_topology.html) also.

I am not affiliated with this company. I've just downloaded and tested their free express version.

Answer (score 0):

I've partially poprted EhCache Java application to .NET The distributed caching is not yet implemented, but on a single node, all original UnitTests pass. Full OpenSource:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/thecache/

I can create a binary drop if you need it (only sourcecode is availble now)

Comment: looks like a neat project. OTOH it looks like overkill for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take the embedded DB route (SQLite, Firebird), but here are some other options:

- [Berkeley DB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libdb-dotnet): not your standard SQL embedded DB, but seems to be the right choice for this kind of task, although [not easily usable from .net](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/07/03/In-search-of-an-embedded-DB.aspx)
- [db4o](http://www.db4o.com): an OODB, very simple interface

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the Caching Application block in the Enterprise Library from MS.  That was recommended as well, but the link points to an article on the Data Access portion of the Enterprise Library.

Here is the link to the Caching Application Block:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc309502.aspx

And specifically, you will want to create a new backing store (if one that persists to disk is not there):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc309121.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Given your recent edits to the question, I suggest that you implement the solution noted in your question as you are very unlikely to find such a naive solution wrapped up in a library for you to reuse.