# How to force C++ allocate memory from disk?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010

I have thousands lines of C++ codes which work well on small text files, but crashes on huge text files (such as 2 GB size). Crash reason: app eats up memory.

Is it possible to allocate memory from disk? Because in most case, hard disk space is much bigger than physical memory. If I can borrow some space from hard disk for my app and return them back after use, then my app has little chance to crash.

Here are my design thoughts:

1. Create a temporary file for file mapping(CreateFileMapping, OpenFileMapping)
2. Force my app to allocate memory from the temporary file
3. Do some clean up work: CloseFileMapping and delete the temporary file

Because I have so much existing code, if my design thought is reasonable, I don't want to redesign my project.

I'm not sure if the design thought is possible to implement. Anybody can help me?

PS: I'm using Visual C++ 2010.

Comment: Design based on `CreateFileMapping` etc. is obviously reasonable; a lot of applications use that approach. What is it you're asking, exactly?

Comment: how to froce my C++ to allocate memory from disk?

Comment: are you on 32bit OS? In that case you might run into virtual memory problem. Otherwise OS Should be able to handle memory management. If on 64bit OS, you might wanna check your allowed VM limit (increase) and you should have sufficient disk space as well for VM.

Comment: It already works that way on Windows, any memory you allocate is backed by the paging file.  What you are running out of is virtual memory address space.  Very simple to fix, just add the x64 configuration and you'll have oodles of address space.

Comment: So, the point of my issue is how to force allocate memory from disk even though there are many free spaces? This is what I am concerned about.

Comment: `CreateFileMapping` and `OpenFileMapping` allocate memory from disk. You don't need to force anything, just switch your application from using `malloc` to your own function that takes memory from the mapped regions. Likewise, in C++ you can override the global `operator new` to take memory from your disk-allocated area.

Comment: Even if you allocate on disk (CreateFileMapping/MapViewOfFile does that) you still need addresses for the entire mapped area. So if you are running out of address space then mapping to disk does not help. And in a 32-bit app you will run out of address space if you try to allocate a contiguous range of only a few hundred MBytes. If that is your problem then you must allocate smaller pieces, or you must upgrade to a 64-bit app.

Comment: Why the downvote ? it's a legitimate question, introducing the non obvious theme of memory mapped iterators / containers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have thousands lines of C++ codes which work well on small text files, but crashes on huge text files (such as 2 GB size). Crash reason: app eats up memory.

You're trying to load entire file into memory on 32bit system (or on 64bit system with 2GB of RAM, or in 32bit application running on 64bit system). On 32bit system 2 gigabyte text file will not fit into memory no matter what you do, because with 32bit addressing you can operate on 2 gigabytes of RAM max, even if it is backed by paging file.

Solutions.

1. (easiest) Process file line-by-line, without loading entire file into memory.
2. Create file mapping. Even with file mapping you will not be able to access entire file at once, but you will be able to map portions of it into memory.

Comment: Actually on 32 bit systems you can operate on 4GB of RAM. However parts of that RAM are already taken.

Comment: Memory mapped are the right thing to do. They are NOT as hard as they look.

Comment: So, the point of my issue is how to force allocate memory from disk even though there are many free spaces? This is what I am concerned about.

Comment: @Tory: No matter what you do,  you CAN'T load entire 2GB file into memory at once on 32bit system. Process it in chunks, or process it as a stream - read line of input, process it, write to output. There's no other way I can think of.

Comment: @celtschk: I know that, but that's not really important in this case. You're free to write better answer, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running out of address space, the first thing is to look around what consumes the  memory and whether it is really necessary to have. You may discover a design change that allows using less, or just keep a some elements in files -- regular files not playing memory.

Another alternative to consider is to emigrate some code to a different process. Using COM it is not hard to start and maintain, and the server can be a 64 bit process dodging the virtual address limit.   I'd expect no more slowdown than with the disk-based idea and it's definitely simpler have.

Oh yeah, we skipped the first thing: maybe converting the project to 64 bit would solve the problem.

If your problem is not with virtual space you just want to consume less than say 1G in any case, your only friend is redesign. For that case I'd not try to fake VM, just do as written in first bullet.

Answer (score 0):

*If* you wrote your algorithms using C++ library, you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/149488/874024) question and related answers.

I actually used memory mapped files to handle large data files, (indexing, sorting, lazy updating), and I found it neither easy nor performing.