# How to avoid thrid party lib(no source codes) to allocate memory from physical memory?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, memory, stl

Suppose this scenario: I refer to a third party lib in my C++ app, but I don't want the third party lib to use my physical memory at all. Instead, I want it to only allocate memory from hard disk. I don't know source codes of third party lib, however as it run in the Windows platform, so I think it's possible to control the memory management with Win32 API.

My problem is how to avoid thrid party lib to allocate memory from physical memory.

Am I going in the wrong direction? Anybody can help me?

PS: I'm using Visual C++ 2010.

Comment: Why would you possibly want this?  Code that is written to work from memory will run several orders of magnitude slower when working from disk, and will hog system resources too.  Why not just take advantage of virtual memory provided by your operating system?

Comment: Data stored on the hard disk has to be copied into main memory before your processor can operate on it...

Comment: @Daniel Pryden I just want to know if it's possible to implement my design thought. It's just my interest.

Comment: Read this: http://cosmal.ucsd.edu/~gert/ece30/CN5.pdf  It will show you why storing data in slow large memory (hard disk) doesn't reduce usage of small fast memory (main memory, cache)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a regular C++ program or library there's no such thing as "allocating physical memory" or "allocating memory from hard disk" in Windows. All "normal" allocation requests are served by virtual memory. It is up to the operating system to decide which virtual memory region will reside in physical RAM and which will reside on disc at any given moment. Neither your program, not the third party library has any control over this.

In other words, the "problem" you seem to describe does not really exist. In a properly designed OS based on virtual memory, the physical RAM is always fully occupied. Unoccupied RAM is wasted RAM - this is the governing principle behind this. That means that the concept of "saving physical RAM" does not really exist in such OS: the physical RAM is always 100% occupied anyway.

In order to make data stored in virtual memory the OS first has to make sure that data is loaded into physical RAM. For this reason, any library that uses memory will have its data loaded inyto physical RAM, regardless of whether you want it or not. Otherwise that third party library simply won't be able to function at all.

Comment: I don't think so, Win32: CreateFileMapping is a little simillar to my request.

Comment: Have a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16997739/how-to-force-c-allocate-memory-from-disk

Comment: @Tory: `MapViewOfFile` returns a pointer referring to physical memory (it's a virtual address, but the data is copied from the hard disk into main memory)

Comment: @Tory: You are misunderstanding the virtual memory mechanism. System virtual memory is by itself nothing else than a file mapping for the system swap file. By doing `CreateFileMappping` for some other file you will simply introduce your own pre-initailized private swap file, which will compete with system swap file for RAM usage. It affects the physical RAM usage in exactly the same way as the regular system swap file does. I.e. it will not "improve" RAM usage in any way at all.

Comment: @Tory: The answer you linked states the same thing. Quite the opposite, it is possible that your `CreateFileMappping` will make things worse by introducing another competitor for physical RAM usage. In a well-implemented system it shouldn't really make things worse, but it won't improve anyhting anyway.

Comment: The semantics are a little bit different from the pagefile... when the mapping is freed, pages of an anonymous mapping are discarded, while pages of a file-linked mapping are flushed back to disk.  But other than that, and the preinitialization Andrey mentioned, memory allocation is mapping of a file.  The file mapped is the pagefile.